# sed: How to join the lines of a record with an empty line delimiting records

Tags: sed

I would like to use 'sed' to joins three lines that make up a record, with records separated by empty lines, and record fields separated by a space.

Here's a snip of data from the file:

```
KDFW
N 32°53.83'
W 097°02.26'

TOC
N 32°48.49'
W 097°01.39'

DART
N 32°17.15'
W 096°48.66'
```

I need to combine the lines like this:

```
KDFW N 32°53.83' W 097°02.26'
TOC N 32°48.49' W 097°01.39'
DART N 32°17.15' W 096°48.66'
```

I'm a novice with sed but pieced together this ugly line.

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /' navlog.txt | sed 'N;s/\n/ /'
```

yea - there is a better way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a single `sed` command without having to pipe, this one should work fine!

```
sed 'N;N;s/\n/ /g;N;s/\n/ /;s/ $//' navlog.txt
KDFW N 32°53.83' W 097°02.26' 
TOC N 32°48.49' W 097°01.39' 
DART N 32°17.15' W 096°48.66'
```

or [Alex Harvey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3787051/alex-harvey) suggestion:

```
sed '$!N;$!N;$!N;s/\n/ /g;s/ $//' navlog.txt 
KDFW N 32°53.83' W 097°02.26' 
TOC N 32°48.49' W 097°01.39' 
DART N 32°17.15' W 096°48.66'
```

Also if your file does end up with an empty line:

```
$ cat navlog.txt 
KDFW
N 32°53.83'
W 097°02.26'

TOC
N 32°48.49'
W 097°01.39'

DART
N 32°17.15'
W 096°48.66'

^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can simplify the command into:

```
sed 'N;N;N;s/\n/ /g;s/ $//' navlog.txt
KDFW N 32°53.83' W 097°02.26' 
TOC N 32°48.49' W 097°01.39' 
DART N 32°17.15' W 096°48.66'
```

**Another great suggestion from [potong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967492/potong) is**:

> If empty lines are to be deleted then it is better to be explicit about it and as all other solutions do add a space at the end of the line, that need to be removed afterwards via (`s/ $//`), it is more direct to use:

```
sed '/\S/!d;N;N;s/\n/ /g'navlog.txt
KDFW N 32°53.83' W 097°02.26' 
TOC N 32°48.49' W 097°01.39' 
DART N 32°17.15' W 096°48.66'
```

Comment: Also, to handle any number of lines, use `'$!N;$!N;$!N; s/\n/ /g'`.

Comment: All these solutions appends a space to the end of the line (except the last if the last line is not empty). Perhaps if empty lines are to be deleted then it is better to be explicit and use `sed '/\S/!d;N;N;s/\n/ /g' file`

Answer (score 3):

I think awk is a way better for this job:

```
awk -v RS="\n\n" 'gsub(/\n/," ")' file
```

this should give you the expected result.

Comment: `RS='\n\n'` is the default when `RS=`

Comment: @Thor, to be a bit pedantic, _If `RS` is null, then records are separated by sequences consisting of a <newline> plus one or more blank lines, leading or trailing blank lines shall not result in empty records at the beginning or end of the input, and a <newline> shall always be a field separator, no matter what the value of `FS` is._

Comment: This might actually fail, if the record is only one line long as `gsub` will return `0`

Comment: @kvantour if in that case, `'1+gsub(...)` may fix it?

Comment: @Kent Yes, but I think it is cleaner to say `'{gsub(/\n/," ")}1'` or even cleaner `'{gsub(/n/,OFS)}1'`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use sed for this. Just use paste:

```
▶ paste - - - - < input
KDFW    N 32°53.83'     W 097°02.26'
TOC     N 32°48.49'     W 097°01.39'
DART    N 32°17.15'     W 096°48.66'
```

Note that as mentioned in the BSD manual for paste:

> If `-` is specified for one or more of the input files, the standard input is used; standard input is read one line at a time, circularly, for each instance of `-`.

Note also that this output is by default tab-separated, and you could have, say, space-separated output too, which seems to be what your sed is doing:

```
▶ paste -d' ' - - - - < input
KDFW N 32°53.83' W 097°02.26' 
TOC N 32°48.49' W 097°01.39' 
DART N 32°17.15' W 096°48.66'
```

Comment: Always nice to see another solution!

Answer (score 2):

**Perl:**

```
perl -pe 's/\n/ / if /./' navlog.txt
```

Or:

```
perl -pe 's/\n/ / if $.%4' navlog.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit shorter than the version of Kent,

```
awk -v RS= '{$1=$1}1'
```

> **If `RS` is null, then records are separated by sequences consisting of a <newline> plus one or more blank lines**, leading or trailing blank lines shall not result in empty records at the beginning or end of the input, and **a <newline> shall always be a field separator, no matter what the value of `FS` is.**

So the trick here is to redefine the first field `$1` by itself, this will rebuild the full record `$0` using `OFS` (default a space) as a field separator, hence merging the lines.

**Remark:** If multiple consecutive spaces or tabs are placed in the original input, they will be replaced with a single space. This can be resolved by defining `FS`:

```
awk -F\n -v RS= '{$1=$1}1'
```